# WPF Backward KeyboardNavigation (Shift+Tab) not working in TreeView

Tags: wpf, treeview

Anyone know why Shift+Tab not working on WPF TreeView?

I'm desperate, couldn't find anywhere a clue on how to solve this?

Is this unsolveable?

Forward navigation works just fine :-(

PLS HELP...

Gili

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2919599/shifttab-not-working-in-treeview-control

Comment: How did it go? I met a similar issue. thanks.