# TreeView tab navigation

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview

I have an UserControl with a Grid that contain a simple TreeView. I'm able to navigate in forward direction (Tab) while in backwards direction (Alt+Tab) not working. (It's focus the last button in my item template).
Do you have any suggestions?

```
    <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding myList}"
          KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Continue" TabIndex="4" IsTabStop="False">

  <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
      <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="True" />
      <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation" Value="Continue"/>
    </Style>
  </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>

  <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding MySubList}">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontWeight="Bold"/>

      <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate>
          <Grid KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local">

            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="Col1"/>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="5"    SharedSizeGroup="Col2"/>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
              <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
              <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
              <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="2147483647" Width="5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" IsTabStop="False"/>

            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Text="Text1"/>
            <TextBox   Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Text1, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" TabIndex="0"/>
            <Button    Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="0" Content="..." TabIndex="1"/>
          </Grid>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
      </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
  </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

Comment: First glance guess without testing, but I'd say remove all the `KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation` declarations and let the defaults do their thing.

Comment: Unfortunately without the KeyboardNavigation declarations, the cursor skip the treeView.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Keyboard navigation in WPF TreeView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6191659/keyboard-navigation-in-wpf-treeview)