# How to use Keyboard Navigation to Online Extensions

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I like to use the keyboard for most everything, however, I'm stuck with one navigation in Visual Studio, I want to get to the Online Extensions and search.

I get to the Extensions by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> and type `Exte` and it's the first in the list. There seems no direct option for online in the quick launch.

So I end up with the follow window and I want to keyboard navigate from the Installed in the tree view down to Online.

[image]

But not sure what key combo to use to do it, <kbd>TAB</kbd> takes me to another panel

<kbd>↓</kbd> <kbd>↑</kbd> keys move through the options for Installed

<kbd>←</kbd> <kbd>→</kbd> don't seem to do much

If I manually use the mouse to select the top "Installed" element, I can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to toggle open the submenus and navigate with arrows between top level tree items, just not sure how to get there without the mouse.

Answer (score 0):

After vaguely remembering Visual Studio is WPF I found :-

[Keyboard navigation in WPF TreeView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6191659/keyboard-navigation-in-wpf-treeview)  which mentions <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> as a negative side effect, however in my case that negative side effect is what I want.

So it ends up being

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>  `Exte` <kbd>Enter</kbd>

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>

<kbd>↓</kbd>

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>

and now in the search box for online extensions