# How to correctly handle keyboard in TreeView?

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, .net-4.8, keyboard-navigation

I have a visual tree similar to the following one:

```
TreeView
    TreeViewItem
        ComboBox
    TreeViewItem
        TextBox
```

The visual tree is made from a few data templates, and a single `DataTemplateSelector`.

The problem, when I press <kbd>↑</kbd> or <kbd>↓</kbd> on the keyboard when the element with the `ComboBox` has focus, `ComboBox` handles that key by switching the selected element.

How to prevent `ComboBox` and `TextBox` controls inside the tree nodes from handling the keys which are used by `TreeView` keyboard navigation?

Comment: Did you try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8299090/4108016)?

Comment: @MuhammadSulaiman No, I don’t need `KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation`. I simply want up/down arrows to work like they do when there’re no editors inside the tree nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable [`KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.keyboardnavigation.directionalnavigation?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) within `TreeViewItem` containers.

> Gets or sets the directional navigation behavior for the children of the element that this property is set on. [...] Directional navigation is invoked by using the arrow keys.

```
<TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
   <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TreeViewItem}}">
      <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation" Value="None"/>
   </Style>
</TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
```