# Shift + Tab is not working for combobox in wpf

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, combobox, tabs

I am working with five text boxes and two comboboxes in xaml.

When I click on <kbd>Tab</kbd> **key** it comes from top to bottom(textboxes to comboboxes),

when I click on <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> it doesn't move from combobox to textbox.

My Combobox is

```
<TextBlock Text="Select" Style="{StaticResource WaterMarkTextBlockStyle}" Visibility="{Binding ElementName=ComboCOM, Path=Text.IsEmpty, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
<ComboBox x:Name="ComboCOM" ItemsSource="{Binding COM.COM}" SelectedItem="{Binding TestResultsEntity.CountryOfOrigin,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay,ValidatesOnDataErrors=True,ValidatesOnExceptions=True,NotifyOnValidationError=True}" Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource ErrorTemplateSilverlightStyle}" IsReadOnly="True" IsHitTestVisible="{Binding TestResultsIsHitTestVisible}" Margin="0" Background="Transparent" >
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <UC:EventTriggerHandler EventName="Loaded">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding GetCOMComboName}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=ComboCOM}"/>
        </UC:EventTriggerHandler>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</ComboBox>
```

Could you please provide me the solution,thanks in advance.

Comment: Are these controls in a treeview?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2919599/shifttab-not-working-in-treeview-control

Comment: No , those are not in tree view

Answer (score 2):

Also this is an old post, I wanted to share my experience.

I came across the same problem with TextBoxes and CheckBoxes inside a Window. Tab worked for jumping to the next Control, Shift+Tab did not work.

The solution was to set `TabIndex` property on all controls in the Window/UserControl.